# How to add elementaryOS-like icons to Linux Mint 18

Tags: linux-mint, icons, menu

My idea came from this picture:

[image: bottom favorite icons in Linux Mint]

I would very much like to have sort of favorite icons in my Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64-bit.

I did not manage to find an answer yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to websites like [Noobslab](http://www.noobslab.com/) or [Gnome-Look](https://www.gnome-look.org/) for themes, icons, mouse cursors, wallpaper etc.

You need to install [Cairo Dock](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/cairo-dock) for a menu like your picture.

I will also suggest you to use Conky which is very interesting and useful.